# How do I get the first element of a dynamic/generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to pass in a generic entity object and get the first in its query.

My intention is to call `FirstOrDefault()` on every table, and try catch for errors in the databases integrity.

It would have been nicer to be able to call it by string parameter e.g. `db.Entity("myTable").FirstOrDefault()` but such a method doesn't seem to exist.

Below is some generic `T` attempt, but i get the object not set to instance error.

```
   // Called with
   //GetFirstObject<myTable>(db.myTable);

    public static void GetFirstObject<T>(object obj)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(IEnumerable<T>).GetMethod("FirstOrDefault");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod();
        generic.Invoke(obj, null);            
    }
```

Comment: What is `db` in this example? An EF DbContext?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is my entity context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TEntity` is the class representing your domain entity, you can try the following:

```
// Called with
// GetFirstObject<myTable>(db);

public static TEntity GetFirstObject<TEntity>(DbContext context) where TEntity : class
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`context.Set<TEntity>()` will return the collection that *represents* the database table for `TEntity`. From there you can use any normal IQueryable extensions defined by LINQ (in this case, `FirstOrDefault`).

Perhaps it's just a working example, but worth pointing out that defining this kind of logic in static helper methods is normally not advisable. I'd suggest researching the 'Generic Repository Pattern' if you want to go down this route, which will be much more maintainable.

Comment: This works great. I had tried using Set but hadn't got it working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `Set<T>()`?

```
public T GetFirstObject<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can also pass *filter expression*:

```
public T GetFirstObject<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression)
    where T : class
{
    return context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filterExpression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesnt work for me without `where TEntity : class` as per other answer. +1 for pointing `Set` out.

Comment: @Doomsknight, you are welcome. I am glad that your issue is solved. I will edit my answer.